# Visual Studio project type guids

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded a Visual Studio project but I can't open it in my copy of Visual Studio 2010. Useless error message:

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

What software do I need to open the project type? It doesn't say.

I actually went and read the `.csproj` file, it tells me it's project type

```xml
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Am I meant to recognise what software I need from this random string? This is absolutely ludicrous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found [a site that lists some known project type GUIDs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726040722/http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) for Visual Studio 2008.

- `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC` looks like a Windows C# project (probably a Class Library project?)
- `786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB` appears to be a [Portable Library project](http://web.archive.org/web/20120829075853/http://www.alexthissen.nl:80/blogs/main/archive/2011/07/07/portable-libraries-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx)

I agree that it's crazy to expect a developer to understand the project type represented by a GUID but whoever supplied the code you downloaded could have indicated what was required to build it!

Comment: I found one more very good consolidated documentation of project type guids used by Visual Studio team. Hope this helps! http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs?msg=4996054#xx4996054xx

Comment: There are used by cloud engineers all the time in CI/CD processes

Answer (score 54):

Here's a list of project type GUIDs:

- `8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B` ASP.NET 5
- `603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0` ASP.NET MVC 1
- `F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325` ASP.NET MVC 2
- `E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401` ASP.NET MVC 3
- `E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47` ASP.NET MVC 4
- `349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21` ASP.NET MVC 5 / Web Application
- `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC` C#
- `9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556` C# (forces use of [SDK project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md#project-type-guids))
- `8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942` C++
- `13B669BE-BB05-4DDF-9536-439F39A36129` CPS barebones project
- `88A30576-7583-4F75-8136-5EFD2C14ADFF` CRM
- `4C25E9B5-9FA6-436c-8E19-B395D2A65FAF` CRM plugin
- `A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124` Database
- `4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8` Database
- `C8D11400-126E-41CD-887F-60BD40844F9E` Database
- `3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A` Deployment Cab
- `06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267` Deployment Merge Module
- `978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA` Deployment Setup
- `AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55` Deployment Smart Device Cab
- `F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C` Distributed System
- `BF6F8E12-879D-49E7-ADF0-5503146B24B8` Dynamics 2012 AX C# in AOT
- `82B43B9B-A64C-4715-B499-D71E9CA2BD60` Extensibility
- `F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786` F#
- `6EC3EE1D-3C4E-46DD-8F32-0CC8E7565705` F# (forces use of [SDK project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md#project-type-guids))
- `95DFC527-4DC1-495E-97D7-E94EE1F7140D` IL project
- `FBB4BD86-BF63-432a-A6FB-6CF3A1288F83` InstallShield
- `E6FDF86B-F3D1-11D4-8576-0002A516ECE8` J#
- `262852C6-CD72-467D-83FE-5EEB1973A190` JScript
- `20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32` Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#)
- `CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8` Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET)
- `581633EB-B896-402F-8E60-36F3DA191C85` LightSwitch Project
- `8BB0C5E8-0616-4F60-8E55-A43933E57E9C` LightSwitch Project
- `ECD6D718-D1CF-4119-97F3-97C25A0DFBF9` LightSwitch Project
- `b69e3092-b931-443c-abe7-7e7b65f2a37f` Micro Framework
- `66A2671D-8FB5-11D2-AA7E-00C04F688DDE` Miscellaneous Files
- `4B160523-D178-4405-B438-79FB67C8D499` Nomad
- `C1CDDADD-2546-481F-9697-4EA41081F2FC` Office/SharePoint App
- `786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB` Portable Class Library
- `66A26720-8FB5-11D2-AA7E-00C04F688DDE` Project Folders
- `D954291E-2A0B-460D-934E-DC6B0785DB48` Shared Project
- `593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2` SharePoint (C#)
- `EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484` SharePoint (VB.NET)
- `F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90` SharePoint Workflow
- `A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B` Silverlight
- `4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884` Smart Device (C#)
- `68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F` Smart Device (VB.NET)
- `2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8` Solution Folder
- `BBD0F5D1-1CC4-42fd-BA4C-A96779C64378` Synergex
- `3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB` Test
- `A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A` Universal Windows Class Library
- `67294A52-A4F0-11D2-AA88-00C04F688DDE` Unloaded Project
- `F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F` VB.NET
- `778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9` VB.NET (forces use of [SDK project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md#project-type-guids))
- `C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387` Visual Database Tools
- `54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C` Visual Studio 2015 Installer Project Extension
- `A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107` Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA)
- `BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33` Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)
- `2CFEAB61-6A3B-4EB8-B523-560B4BEEF521` Web Deployment
- `E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A` Web Site
- `3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699` Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
- `76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39` Windows Phone 8/8.1 Blank/Hub/Webview App
- `C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43` Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (C#)
- `DB03555F-0C8B-43BE-9FF9-57896B3C5E56` Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (VB.NET)
- `60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548` Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
- `BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3` Windows Store (Metro) Apps & Components
- `930C7802-8A8C-48F9-8165-68863BCCD9DD` WiX Setup
- `14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079` Workflow (C#)
- `D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8` Workflow (VB.NET)
- `32F31D43-81CC-4C15-9DE6-3FC5453562B6` Workflow Foundation
- `EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF` Xamarin.Android / Mono for Android
- `6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B` Xamarin.iOS / MonoTouch
- `F5B4F3BC-B597-4E2B-B552-EF5D8A32436F` MonoTouch Binding
- `6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596` XNA (Windows)
- `2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2` XNA (XBox)
- `D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433` XNA (Zune)

Some of these are given different names under different versions of Visual Studio, so if you don't see an exact name match, look for a similar or related name.

Comment: Thanks that you've ordered the SDK style project id.

Comment: Is there a Microsoft reference for these values? I can't find documentation for any of this. Where does this info come from? I'm guessing this is internal info that we just have to be lucky enough to hear from a Microsoft engineer.

Comment: It looks like `D954291E-2A0B-460D-934E-DC6B0785DB48` is specified twice. Once as `Shared Project` and another time as `Windows Store App Universal`

Comment: You're right. I've removed the _Windows Store App Universal_ entry as I don't believe it's correct.

Answer (score 15):

Visual Studio projects system architecture uses GUIDs to identifiy the type of the project. You could find online lists like these below:

- [INFO: List of known project type Guids](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)
- [Visual Studio Projects - Project Type GUIDs](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html)

Such GUIDs allows the Visual Studio to recognize what type of project user opened and use appropriate tools and editors. To uderstand better what do I mean - read this post for example: [Opening an ASP.NET MVC project without having ASP.NET MVC installed: The project type is not supported by this installation](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/01/20/opening-an-asp-net-mvc-project-without-having-asp-net-mvc-installed-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation.aspx)

Comment: Where do these definitions come from? Are we really supposed to believe non-Microsoft, obscure web sites reverse engineered these values themselves? These sites provide no references. Are we supposed to just believe their values?

Comment: Sort of. Project Type GUID is a unique key used in registry to identify specific project type. Visual Studio keeps all stuff (editors, projects, menu items, tools, etc. ) in system registry. This IDE load's everything from there. Really interesting architecture solution IMHO. So those GUIDs are known ones for standard project types.

Comment: If anyone creates a custom extensibility package for VS with [custom project type inside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-projects) (e.g. you created project type for IDK - ActionScript language) and you used some GUIDs for your package, project type, language services and so on. Those GUIDs are added to registry when you install your package (MSI or via VSIX package, etc). And When IDE loads it picks your custom project up and it is involved to Add New Project dialog, and far and so on .