# Why ProjectTypeGuids is needed in visual studio project file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I found sometimes the ProjectTypeGuids is missing in C# projects and sometimes not.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

I didn't see any impact if it is missing. While seeing some guys were also asking the significance of it, i always notice this link below shared in the answers which shows the list of ProjectTypeGuids defined by MS.

[List of Visual Studio Project Type GUIDs](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

Unfortunately, very few information is given by MS besides the post below where one MS employee answered it was for project aggregation. But who knows what project aggregation means.

[What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9d05cdc-96a1-4044-95d8-a4f8885a660a/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-file?forum=vsx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio project type guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802198/visual-studio-project-type-guids)

Comment: Historically, it was basically just so that it started loading the right tools to process your project - and to check that you even *have* the tools required. I rarely see them any more, thanks to SDK-style project files