# How do I define a C# Unit Test Project using CMake?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, csproj, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm converting some existing C# projects to be defined in CMake -- moving from the previous `include_external_msproject()` directive to the newer full support for C#.

But I'm not seeing how to convert projects of the `Visual C# Unit Test Project` type. I'm able to build them as libraries, and compile them successfully -- but Visual Studio doesn't show them as unit test projects, just as regular libraries. Most crucially, the tests aren't visible to the Test Explorer.

---

Things I've already tried include:

- Adding `TestProjectType=UnitTest` as a target property:
  `<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>`
- Adding a reference path, as follows, as a target property:
  `<ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)/Common Files/microsoft shared/VSTT/$(VisualStudioVersion)/UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>`
- Adding `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` as a project reference (using CMake's `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES` property).

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015, CMake 3.13.2, .NET Framework 4.5.2 (but I suspect the issue isn't specific to my particular version combination).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually adding `<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>`, made my unit test project show up as unit test. Trying to figure out how to do that using cmake.

Update: the following shows the project as unittest

```
set_target_properties(${target_name}
PROPERTIES
VS_GLOBAL_PROJECT_TYPES "{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"
)
```

Documentation for `VS_GLOBAL_PROJECT_TYPES` is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_PROJECT_TYPES.html).
I found this documentation for Project Guid: [Visual Studio project type guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802198/visual-studio-project-type-guids)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @bhardwajs, your answer helped me.
You can also add TestProjectType to global properties:

```
set_target_properties(${target_name} PROPERTIES
VS_GLOBAL_TestProjectType "UnitTest"
VS_GLOBAL_PROJECT_TYPES "{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}")
```