# Item Templates Sometimes Missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, sometimes new item templates are missing, and it seems to be tied to the particular project to which I'm trying to add an item.

Although both show up as "C#" projects...
[image]
...in "Logging", for WPF items, I have only UserControl (WPF) as an option:
[image: Only UserControl is available]

However, in "SanityCheck", I have a much-more-full list of WPF options:
[image: Many more WPF options available]

The only difference I can easily see so far is that the one ("Logging") is a Class Library project while the other ("SanityCheck") is a Windows Application project.  However, changing Logging to Windows Application doesn't make more options available, and I *ought* to be able to create a Window in a Class Library, right?

I also noticed that Logging didn't contain all the same references as SanityCheck, so I added all the ones that seemed possibly-related, and that also didn't make any difference in the set of templates available.

So how do I get my Logging project to let me add a WPF Window?

Comment: inspect (and compare) .csproj file. I expect there will be  different <ProjectTypeGuids> blocks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802198/visual-studio-project-type-guids

Comment: Interesting.  The "Logging" .csproj doesn't have a <ProjectTypeGuids> element at all.  I'm going to try adding the same one from "SanityCheck" and see what happens...

Comment: ...and that magically made all the other C# WPF options appear.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment from [ASh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash) and the list referred to from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802198/visual-studio-project-type-guids), I determined that the cause was a missing `<ProjectTypeGuids>` block in the Logging.csproj file.  I copied the one from the SanityCheck.csproj file and now all the C# WPF templates are available.  So far I haven't encountered any negative side-effects to this solution.  Time will tell.