# Can't Change Project to x86 in Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with over 170 projects in it.  I recently needed to add two more projects to this solution.  For reasons that are not relevant to this question, the solution is built as at x86.

When I open Configuration Manager, and scroll to my new projects, they say "Any CPU".  To change that I select `<New...>`:

[image: Selecting New]

It brings up a dialog to make the new entry.  I fill it out like this:

[image: New Profile]

When I select OK, it flashes for a second, then goes back to "Any CPU":

[image: Still Any CPU]

I also tried selecting `<Edit...>` and I get this:

[image: Edit has no options]

The Remove button is locked out and I don't have any other options.

**How can I get an x86 option setup for my new projects?**

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem when I converted `C#` projects into `C# SDK style` projects.
I found that after conversion, the project type GUID in the solution file did not change from `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = ...` to `Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = ...`.

Solution of this problem in my case was to **delete** this project from VS solution and **add** it again. You can also **manually** edit solution file (`.sln`) and change wrong project-type-GUID.

In your case, try to check the project type GUID in the solution file and change GUID manually. The list of project type GUIDs can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485177/28901).

Comment: This was part but not the whole solution for me. With the C# SDK project format the default platform is 'AnyCPU'. I had to add '<Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>' for the additional platforms for this project to show up.