# Not able to open VS 2010 Pro MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I try to open an MVC Project which was developed win VS 2010 with .Net Framework 4.0, using the same kind of VS, an error

> "The project type is not supported by this installation."

is thrown.

I observed I don't have NuGet packages installed. Is this the problem ?

Though I am able to open it using web developer 2010 Express, when i run it

> "Error   It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS."

is thrown.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation) post for a possible solution.

Comment: make sure that the correct MVC version is installed in your system

Answer (score 0):

Check this out i found them already posted on StackOverFlow you should really do some search before asking :) [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level)
And
[Another One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on)