# Visual Studio does not have following project types installed or does not support them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I am trying to run a windows Phone 8 Project. And I get a message that this project type is not supported. so I googled what it meant and I got the following solution.

[The project type is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation/8809433#8809433)

Now, this solution tells me to find out what the Project Guid requires. I have the Project Guid as :

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Now, how do I find out what is required to run this kind of Project. I know that `fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc` is for a C# project.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

Comment: Looks like the other one is for the Windows Phone SDK (7.1) - can't be sure but that's what a search turns up

Comment: Are you seeing this error message when selecting File->New Project->Windows Phone 8 project?  If so, have you tried re-installing the SDK?

Comment: Thanks @earthling and Charleh. Looks like I don't have an SDK for Windows Phone. Problem Solved. I reinstalled my windows and somehow I missed the installation of Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: Karan, if your problem was solved, please post the answer. I ended up here because I have the same problem.