# Error opening solution in VS2010 - The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, guid

When trying to open a solution in VS2010 Professional, I get this error:

```
The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

I already looked at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation)** thread and none of it seemed to relate to my specific situation.

When I view the csproj in notepad, it shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>False</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>True</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't tell what kind of project that is. What project template was used to create it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell that.  After googling the GUID, it shows "Web Application".  So I assume that the template used to create this was "ASP.NET Web Application"

Comment: Yes, someone else created this.  I figured out the problem.  I was viewing "projectName.csproj.user" (not sure what that is exactly).  What I needed to be looking at was "projectName.csproj".  Then it showed all the <ProjectTypeGuids>.  First one I searched was MVC3.  Installed MVC 3 and BOOM!  Problem solved.  

Thanks for your time.  Also, should I post this as the answer to my question?  Not sure of the rules on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is a 2010 template? Or, is it a MVC or Web API project? You might need to install MVC to fix it.