# How do I download Visual Studio Updates directly from Internet?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm new here and now I found out that I should use the Visual Studio to complete my project; I downloaded the latest version of Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and installed it on Windows 10, but after a while just crashed a lot, I don't know why! but fixed automatically (I hope this will not happen again)! I used the Lynda to learn about Visual Studio and downloaded the exercise files form the teacher and opened that in my VS2015 but I faced with an Error with this title:

> ```
> The project type is not supported by this installation
> ```

I used google to search about this issue and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation) but my problem not solved yet! I used Microsoft support team and they told me you should Update your product! but mine is updated to the latest version!
whatever I opened the exercise `.sln` file and the visual studio popped up an error that contains these errors:
[the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLXoV.png) ;
after i closed the VS just the update window popped up and some libraries listed with a blink cube left side and the default selection, was 3 type of files, but i didn't know what was that and just clicked the next button, i have a problem with internet limitation time and some bandwidth issues so i can't use the VS program to download the updates (that was 8 GB), so is there any option to use it that will allow me to download the libraries directly by some download manager like IDM? and is there any option to convert the errors to find the links for updates? i mean that i want to find the issues the find the solutions and download them from the internet directly!
here I attached the `.sln` file as text to show you what's my misunderstood:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ConsoleApp", "ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp.csproj", "{47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsFormsApp", "WindowsFormsApp\WindowsFormsApp.csproj", "{6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ClassLibrary", "ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.csproj", "{FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsStoreApp", "WindowsStoreApp\WindowsStoreApp.csproj", "{0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WpfApp", "WpfApp\WpfApp.csproj", "{82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PhoneApp", "PhoneApp\PhoneApp.csproj", "{7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsPhoneGame", "WindowsPhoneGame\WindowsPhoneGame\WindowsPhoneGame.csproj", "{3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsPhoneGameContent", "WindowsPhoneGame\WindowsPhoneGameContent\WindowsPhoneGameContent.contentproj", "{7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}"
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "MvcApp", "MvcApp\MvcApp.vbproj", "{C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|ARM = Debug|ARM
        Debug|Mixed Platforms = Debug|Mixed Platforms
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Debug|Windows Phone = Debug|Windows Phone
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|ARM = Release|ARM
        Release|Mixed Platforms = Release|Mixed Platforms
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
        Release|Windows Phone = Release|Windows Phone
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {47559526-5F7B-4C95-BD79-8104313FE616}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E9AD046-1FD6-4F15-9FDB-A795E9640A7F}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FE7F2CD5-C906-48CA-BFBC-D86D8517E7A1}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|ARM.Build.0 = Debug|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|ARM.Deploy.0 = Debug|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Win32.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x64.Deploy.0 = Debug|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Debug|x86.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|ARM.Build.0 = Release|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|ARM.Deploy.0 = Release|ARM
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Win32.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x64.Deploy.0 = Release|x64
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {0359368D-56DD-4D41-92AC-660BCAD01369}.Release|x86.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {82408406-2AB9-4BF5-9053-8626585D532B}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|ARM.Build.0 = Debug|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|ARM.Deploy.0 = Debug|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Win32.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Debug|x86.Deploy.0 = Debug|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|ARM.Build.0 = Release|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|ARM.Deploy.0 = Release|ARM
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Win32.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}.Release|x86.Deploy.0 = Release|x86
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Windows Phone.Build.0 = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|Windows Phone.Deploy.0 = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Windows Phone.Build.0 = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|Windows Phone.Deploy.0 = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {3C2D8D0D-BD11-4B30-B6FD-E5E01DA48807}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {7C09FE16-487D-4184-8EE4-54CE137FDFC7}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Windows Phone
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|Windows Phone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C7780198-6321-4109-BFE4-1FE653E55766}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

for example that i want to find the solution for this error:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PhoneApp", "PhoneApp\PhoneApp.csproj", "{7683D457-C160-4E68-9B8C-E70C6CE0083C}"
```

how do i search the GUIDs to find out what they require?
like this one: `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`
thank you for reading my question, please help me.

Comment: thank you @Steve for your attention.

Comment: From the picture posted it is possible that you haven't installed the libraries and the environment required to compile Windows Phone Apps (these components are optional and need to be explicitily selected during setup) You could re-execute (modify) the installation of VS or just go to the Build->Configuration Manager menu and deselect the projects that require the Windows Phone components

Comment: Thanks @Steve ; my problem solved, but is there any way to download the updates directly from Microsoft server?

Comment: You run the setup again and choose the modify option to select the missing ones